# Fails to run the script as Jython. But works with python without any issue

Tags: java, python, jython, jython-2.5, jython-2.7

I'm kinda newbie to Jython. I'm trying to execute a python script through a Java program (using Jython). Inside the python script I'm trying to call a method of some external library (called petl). When I try to execute the script with python (As: python script.py) it executes without any problem. But when I try to access the script with Jython (As: jython script.py) it gives me the following error.

P.S: I can run simple python scripts without any problem. But when I try to access an external library function through the script it gives me an error.

Can anyone please give me an workaround or some advice? Thanks in advance.

Python Script:

```
import petl as etl

table1 = etl.fromcsv('Books.csv')
table2 = etl.sort(table1, 'ACCOUNT_ID')
etl.tocsv(table2, source='NewBooks.csv',encoding='utf-8')
```

Error Stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 5, in <module>
    etl.tocsv(table2, source='NewBooks.csv',encoding='utf-8')
  File "C:\Jython\Lib\site-packages\petl\io\csv.py", line 106, in tocsv
    tocsv_impl(table, source=source, encoding=encoding, errors=errors,
  File "C:\Jython\Lib\site-packages\petl\io\csv_py2.py", line 50, in tocsv_impl
    _writecsv(table, source=source, mode='wb', **kwargs)
  File "C:\Jython\Lib\site-packages\petl\io\csv_py2.py", line 74, in _writecsv
    for row in rows:
  File "C:\Jython\Lib\site-packages\petl\transform\sorts.py", line 271, in _iter
nocache
    hdr = next(it)
  File "C:\Jython\Lib\site-packages\petl\io\csv_py2.py", line 30, in __iter__
    codec = getcodec(self.encoding)
  File "C:\Jython\Lib\site-packages\petl\io\base.py", line 12, in getcodec
    codec = codecs.lookup(encoding)
        at org.python.core.codecs.normalizestring(codecs.java:62)
        at org.python.core.codecs.access$200(codecs.java:29)
        at org.python.core.codecs$CodecState.lookup(codecs.java:1695)
        at org.python.core.codecs.lookup(codecs.java:58)
        at org.python.modules._codecs.lookup(_codecs.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)

java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Does it fail if you run it using a standalone `jython` executable instead of embedding it? Might be related: [Unable to use the codecs module when embedding Jython](http://bugs.jython.org/issue1722)

Comment: Yes sir, it fails to run using a standalone jython executable too. But it runs when I run it as a standalone python. (With "python script.py" command)

Comment: What is the output of `jython -c "import codecs, sys; print codecs.lookup('utf8'), sys.path, sys.executable"`?

Comment: Output for the above command is: <codecs.CodecInfo object for encoding utf-8 at 0x2> ['', 'C:\\Jython\\Lib\\site-
packages\\jip-0.9.4-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Jython\\Lib\\site-packages\\requests-2.7.0-
py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Jython\\Lib', '__classpath__', '__pyclasspath__/', 'C:\\Jython\
\Lib\\site-packages'] C:\Jython\bin\jython.exe

Comment: you should put the output in your question (to format it properly). Have you noticed that `C:\Jython` != `C:\jython2.7.0`? Use the right `jython` executable, run `jython -c "import codecs; print codecs.lookup(None)"`. To workaround the issue, try to pass the encoding to `tocsv()` function explicitly (a string, not None).

Comment: Sir, My Jython directory is "C:\Jython", not "C:\jython2.7.0". I also tried to pass the encoding to tocsv function explicitly as you said: ("etl.tocsv(table2,source='NewBooks.csv',encoding='utf-8')") Still gives me the error. I'm stuck here for 3 days on my final year Research project. :(

Comment: do you see `C:\jython2.7.0` in your question? What error does `encoding='utf-8'` lead to? Update your question and include the full traceback (and the corresponding code).

Comment: "C:\jython2.7.0" was my previous Jython directory. Sorry about that. I updated the current code and error trackback. Thanks for your effort to help me :)

Comment: Run a debugger (`python -mpdb you_script.py` or use your IDE) and see where `encoding` is replaced with None.

Comment: Finally solved the issue. Your instructions helped me a lot to sort me out this issue. I'll upload the correct code. Thank you so for your support :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly pass the value for encoding when calling both fromcsv() and tocsv() functions.

```
import petl as etl

table1 = etl.fromcsv(source='Books.csv',encoding='utf-8')
table2 = etl.sort(table1, 'ACCOUNT_ID')
etl.tocsv(table2, source='NewBooks.csv',encoding='utf-8')
```